# docker stack deployment failing

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-stack

I'm trying to learn Docker, I'm using it with a 5 machine (1 leader, 4 workers) on http://play-with-docker.com and following a Udemy tutorial.  I the tutorial about Docker stack, the instructor gives an example of this code:

```
version: "3"
services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    depends_on:
      - mysql:mysql
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    networks:
      - frontend
    deploy:
      replicas: 6
      restart-policy:
        condition: on-failure

  mysql:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    networks:
      - frontend
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]

  visualizer:
    image: dockersamples/visualizer:stable
    ports:
      - 9000:8080
    networks:
      - frontend
    stop_grace_period: 1m 30s
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]


    networks:
      frontend:
```

He then runs it just fine in the video and everything composes properly.

I feel like I was very careful typing in his instructions, but when I run this file I get

```
$ docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-stack.yml wordP
service mysql: undefined network "frontend"
```

I've gone over this a hundred times letter by letter, space by space, line by line.  I've poured through Docker's official documentation looking for something that has maybe changed betweek versions.  Can anyone see an obvious problem with what I"m trying?

Thanks.

Kyle

Answer (score 2):

Yaml files are space sensitive (similar to python code). The network section at the end of the file needs to be that the top level, not indented within your visualizer service.

```
version: "3"
services:

  wordpress:
  # ...

# these next lines need to be unindented 4 spaces:
networks:
  frontend:
```